# Post SOAP Dynamic Envelope from Bash Script

Tags: xml, bash, soap, sed, xsd

I want to post a soap envelope via bash.

I can do this like that

```
#curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:"  -d @request.xml -X POST http://soap.sd.testdomain.com.tr/webservice/test
```

request.xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:tos="http://xx">    
<soapenv:Header/>    
<soapenv:Body>
<tos:createSend soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<customerSend xsi:type="java:CustomerSend" xmlns:java="java:com.deneme.test.model">
<actionId xsi:type="xsd:long"></actionId>
<actionStatus xsi:type="xsd:int">2</actionStatus>
</customerSend>
</tos:createSend>    
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

After first success this request i want to make a dynamic request by reading the data from file then make request for each line of the file .

here is the example of my file

1;2;AT-902737;Note;4

1;2;AT-902738;Note;4

I want to pass the AT-902737 parameters as actionId 
and 4 parameter as actionStatus

I tried to start the script but i can not complete :(

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS=";", read -r -a input; do

printf "%s\n" "${input[2]}" "${input[4]}"


#sed -i 's#\(<actionId xsi:type="xsd:long">\)*\(</actionId>\)#\1'"${input[2]}"'\2#g' request.xml

#curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:"  -d @request.xml -X POST http://soap.sd.testdomain.com.tr/webservice/test
```

I tried but can not be succeed because ${input[2]} parameter shown as ${input[2]} in XML file. not as AT-902737

Comment: Your scripts basically work for me. I only had to the replace the `*` in your `sed` search pattern by `.*`.

Comment: is there any way of doing this on linux without using curl ?